# about xx-sw600dp of andorid4.0

Tags: android, launcher

In android 4.0 resource there are new drawable ,layout ,value folder for example drawable-sw600dp,layout-sw600dp,value-sw600dp. I want  to know what the  affect about them. I am also to know the phone how to call the many layout folders.at 2.x phone first match 320*240_layout ,if no this ,then other hdpi phone called layout. But I found at4.x if have 320*240_layout,other hdpi phone not use layout folder also use 320*240,am  I right?

[image]

[image: second image]

You see the two pics, they are the luncher4.0.1,first launcher only modify the package of launcher not modify any code.
The second pic is default launcher2. I  don't know why can difference, they run at the same phone Samsung galaxy one, and the code are  the same.
First I think the  problem is resolution cause, but I think it not. Can you tell me why show the result? thank you

Comment: if you cannot understand the question,you can see the difference between the images. if you cannot know luncher,you cannot know the question.

Comment: @userSeven7s Google Translate formats English in Human-Readable format. The grammar spacing is generally correct, and it capitalises recognised nouns and the first word in a sentence. The OP may have used it to aid in his translations, but he certainly didn't post it's raw output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem. In the source code, I deleted `layout.createHardwareLayer();`.
Now the effect looks like the second pic.